# react-router typescript error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

Trying to initialize router with react and typescript but getting bunch of errors

[image: Errors]

I tried already install `npm install @types/history`
But nothing changed 
Hope your help. 
Thanks

**My packge.json**

```
"dependencies": {
"@types/lodash": "^4.14.50",
"@types/react": "^0.14.55",
"@types/react-dom": "^0.14.19",
"@types/redux-form": "^6.3.2",
"animate": "^1.0.0",
"animate.css": "^3.5.2",
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.5",
"node-sass": "^4.1.1",
"postcss-smart-import": "^0.6.6",
"react": "^15.4.1",
"react-dom": "^15.4.1",
"react-redux": "^5.0.2",
"react-router": "^3.0.1",
"redux": "^3.6.0",
"redux-form": "^6.4.3",
"typings": "^2.1.0"
},

 "devDependencies": {
    "@types/history": "^4.5.0",
    "@types/react-router": "^2.0.44",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.17",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "precss": "^1.4.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.3.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^1.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "typescript": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0"
  }
```

Comment: So, the typescript compiler can't find a few types. Can you post a code snippet? Don't post all of the code, just the relevant portions.

Comment: U wanted this? or?

`import {Router, browserHistory} from 'react-router';`

`ReactDOM.render(<Router history={browserHistory} routes={Routes} />, document.getElementById("miramir-app"));`

Comment: hmmm...also, please update the question with your tsconfig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue for the time being I copied the contents of the DefinitelyTyped history v2

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/history/v2

Into my node_modues/@types/history folder

Comment: Just a note this is just a tmp fix until the @types/history or @types/react-router is updated